# Python3 "Class factory" - ex: API(token).MyClass()

Tags: python, design-patterns, factory

I'm writing a python REST client for an API.

The API needs *authentication* and I would like to have many API client objects running on the same script.

My current code for the API is something like this:

```py
class RestAPI:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    self.fetch()

  def fetch(self):
    requests.get(self.url+self.id, auth=self.apikey)

class Purchase(RestAPI):
  url = 'http://example.com/purchases/'
class Invoice(RestAPI):
  url = 'http://example.com/invoices/'
...
```

And I would like to use the API like that:

```py
api_admin = Api('adminmytoken')
api_user = Api('usertoken')
…
amount = api_admin.Purchase(2).amount

api_user.Purchase(2).amount # raises because api_user is not authorized for this purchase
```

The problem is that *each object* needs to know it's **apikey** depending on the client I want to use.

That pattern looks like to me to a "class factory": all the classes of RestAPI need to know of the provided token.

How is it possible to cleanly do that without giving manually the token to each model ?

Comment: Read about [class-variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: @stovfl : I did, but I don't think that you can have a same class variable with different results given the context (in this case: `api_admin` and `api_user`).

Comment: ***"class variable with different results"***: Thats true, maybe i missunderstood your question. Extend your example to see your intention.

Comment: I don't think inheritance is the way to go. The factory is probably the right answer, but each object should *not* know the apikey. If anything, there should be one interface that knows the apikey and the low-level calls. Then your objects use the interface to get information, and they know nothing about the api_keys

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that your design is a little backwards. Inheritance might not be the key here. What I might do is take the api token as an argument on the User class, then that gets passed to an instance-level binding on the Rest interface:

```py
class APIUser:
    def __init__(self, id, api_key, **kwargs):
        self._rest = Interface(id, api_key, **kwargs)

    def purchase(self, some_arg):
        # the interface itself does the actual legwork, 
        # and you are simply using APIUser to call functions with the interface
        return self._rest.fetch('PURCHASE', some_arg)


class Interface:
    methods = {
        # call you want  (class   url)
        'PURCHASE': (Purchase, 'https://myexample.com/purchases'),
        'INVOICE': (Invoice, 'https://myexample.com/invoices'),
        # add more methods here
    }
    def __init__(self, id, key):
        self.id = id
        self.key = key
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def _fetch(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some methods to go get data
        try:
            # use the interface to look up your class objects
            # which you may or may not need
            _class, url = self.methods[method]
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Got unsupported method, expected "
                        f"{'\n'.join(self.methods)}") from e

        headers = kwargs.pop('headers', {})

        # I'm not sure the actual interface here, maybe you call the
        # url to get metadata to populate the class with first...
        req = requests.Request(_class.http_method, url+self.id, auth=self.key, headers=headers).prepare()
        resp = self.session.send(req)

        # this will raise the 401 ahead of time
        resp.raise_for_status()

        # maybe your object uses metadata from the response
        params = resp.json()
        # return the business object only if the user should see it
        return _class(*args, **kwargs, **params)


class Purchase:
    http_method = 'GET'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some setup here with your params passed by the json
        # from the api


user = APIUser("token", "key") # this is my user session
some_purchase = user.purchase(2) # will raise a 401 Unauthorized error from the requests session

admin = APIUser("admintoken", "adminkey") # admin session
some_purchase = admin.purchase(2)

# returns a purchase object

some_purchase.amount
```

There are a few reasons why you might want to go this way:

1. You don't get the object back if you aren't allowed to see it
2. Now the rest interface is in control of who sees what, and that's implicitly tied to the user object itself, without every other class needing to be aware of what's going on
3. You can change your url's in one place (if you need to)
4. Your business objects are just business objects, they don't need to do anything else

By separating out what your objects actually are, you still only need to pass the api keys and tokens once, to the User class. The Interface is bound on the instance, still giving you the flexibility of multiple users within the same script.

You also get the models you call on explicitly. If you try to take a model, you have to call it, and that's when the Interface can enforce your authentication. You no longer need your authentication to be enforced by your business objects

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But then, it is really cumbersome when I'll have many models (ex: Account, Purchase, Invoice). I'd need to always pass the api_key when I'll want to "take" a model, which seems not very practical.

Comment: @Frank Maybe this is a bit more practical

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this, and the example above could probably use a good bit of refining, but this way you've separated out the api calling layer from everything else. I agree that `Account`, `Purchase`, and `Invoice` should *not* need the api-key